# What to do when the seller of a property does not honor a memorandum of sale?

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, house

I put an offer on a property which got accepted, and the memorandum of sales (MOS) has been created, but the seller still chose to go with another buyer. What is possible in this situation? Does the MOS help here at all? I know it's now a legally binding contract between the buyer and seller.

Comment: Important check: is this in England/Wales or Scotland? The answer is potentially very different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A memorandum of sale is [not a legally binding contract](https://propertysalewatchdog.com/what-is-a-memorandum-of-sale/), it contains details of the property you're going to buy. Either party can withdraw from the sale at any point until [exchange of contracts](https://www.moneyhelper.org.uk/en/homes/buying-a-home/contract-exchange-completion-when-buying-a-home).

You could increase your offer to try to persuade the seller to sell to you instead of the new buyer or move on and find another property instead.

Next time you might consider taking out homebuyers protection insurance once a memorandum of sale has been issued, which would compensate you if the seller withdrew from the sale.